# Sum the total line length inside grid using Python

Tags: python, gis, polygon, polyline, shapely

#### 1. Introduction

- A polylines file which in *.shp* format represent the roadmap of somewhere.
- I want to raster the whole area with grid network.
- Each grid should sum the road length inside it.

This is what I pursued.(This figure is a result of similar project which shown in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119993/convert-line-shapefile-to-raster-value-total-length-of-lines-within-cell))
[image]

#### 2. My Attempt

2.1 read the polylines

For now, I was thinking about using *shapely* package to cope with.

```
road_file =road = map.readshapefile('roadmap','roadmap',zorder =1,)
```

The roadmap shows like
[image]

2.2 Split it into multi-lines

```
# x1,y1 --> start point; y1,y2 --> end point
road = {"name":[],"x1":[],"x2":[],"y1":[],"y2":[],"distance":[]}
l = []
ll = []
i = 0
for info, shape in zip(roadmap.info, roadmap):
    i+=1
    road["name"].append("road" + str(i))
    l = info
    ll.append(info)
    road["x1"].append(shape[0][0])
    road["x2"].append(shape[-1][0])
    road["y1"].append(shape[0][1])
    road["y2"].append(shape[-1][1])
```

The result:
[image]

2.3 Generate the grid network

The grid network will be all over the area, and I'll transform each grid into a shapely squire.

[image]

2.4 Sum the length of each road inside of the grid

This step I didn't write in code. And here is an simple example for one grid with one road(line, indeed).

```
import shapely
polygon = [(1.0, 1.0), (2.0, 1.0), (2.0, 2.0), (1,2), (1, 1)]
shapely_poly = shapely.geometry.Polygon(polygon)
line = [(1, 2), (2,1)]
shapely_line = shapely.geometry.LineString(line)
intersection_line = list(shapely_poly.intersection(shapely_line).coords)
```

In this way, I can get the intersection length of one grid with one line.

But when my data was vast(100x100 grids & 200 roads), the loop would be so slow. There must be some alternative way to deal with this issue.

Any advices would be appreciate!

#### Update an alternative method using rpy2

```
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
rgdal  = importr('rgdal')
raster = importr("raster")
rgeos  = importr("rgeos") 

rscript = """
##Reference the question I mentioned above
roads <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer ="roadmap")
roads_utm <- spTransform(roads, CRS("+init=epsg:21037"))
roads_utm_rst <- raster(extent(roads_utm), ncol = 100,nrow =100,crs = projection(roads_utm))
lengths <- sapply(1:ncell(roads_utm_rst), function(i) {
  tmp_rst <- roads_utm_rst
  tmp_rst[i] <- 1
  tmp_shp <- rasterToPolygons(tmp_rst)

  if (gIntersects(roads_utm, tmp_shp)) {
    roads_utm_crp <- crop(roads_utm, tmp_shp)
    roads_utm_crp_length <- gLength(roads_utm_crp)
    return(roads_utm_crp_length)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
})
"""

length = r(rscripts)
```

Then, *length* is a list contain length information of every grid, then I can use python directly to analyse it.

Comment: What do you think about using QGis? Maybe it will be a bit of work to find out how to perform your desired operations, but I think it sould have robust and efficient ways to do what you want. And it is scriptable in python.

Comment: I have tried _QGIS_, but I find it difficult too. I tried several time to generate fishnet and sum the length.

Comment: Some operations might be intrinsically slow. Are you at least getting correct results, even if slow? And how slow is it? Minutes? Hours?

Comment: I tried following [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175221/how-to-calculate-the-intersection-within-the-grid-and-saving-to-the-grid). I haven't tried vast data in QGIS now. I think it will be qualified to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use shapely's [MultiLineString](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#MultiLineString) object.

Then, instead of having a list of `LineString` to iterate, you could perform the intersection only once for each grid cell.

```
roadLengthInCell = roadsMultiLineString.intersection(cellRect).length
```

Comment: It can sum all line in one grid for once? That'll be awesome!

Comment: If your road network spans a large area, you should consider Earth sphericity, since geographic distance calculations are not the same as cartesian/rectangular distance.

Comment: @HanZhengzu yes, that is the idea. A MultiLineString is a single object, composed of all the roads. The `length` property gives you the sum of all its lines, it is explicitly examplified in the docs I linked. There you can see how to create one, too (you should pass a list of roads, where each road is a list of 2-tuples)

Comment: Still quite slow because you have to loop through all the polygons